# jQuery.validation for email, phone and numbers

Tags: jquery, html

with the jQuery.validation plugin is it possible to set a field for telephone numbers only, zipcodes only, and email only. then when the submit button is press display the error next to the button?

I've looked into HTML5 and it has input types for Telephone, Numbers, and Emails but it doesn't seem to be support by all the newer browsers yet. So I'm looking for a simple method without having to redesign my FORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course its possible. Have you looked at the [demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)? Or the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

If the validations that ship with `jquery.validate.js` aren't enough you can check out the ones in `additional-methods.js`, or if worse comes to worse, you can always extend the validator with your custom validation method.

edit:

phoneUS, phoneUK, mobileUK, ziprange, email2 are in `additional-methods.js`
number, email are in `jquery.valiadte.js`

Comment: thanks this is a good demo, not bloated like the others i've seen

Comment: Its the one jQuery Validator offers. Does it answer your question?